# issue with package pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

I updated R and RStudio recently and was unable to compile PDFs in RStudio using knitr and pdfLaTex with MikTex.  I was able to fix that issue by following
[ribnikov's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582041/r-sweave-does-not-compile-to-pdf/582528#582528)

I re-installed an older version of MikTex.  I can now get the PDF to compile, but when I try to use package pdfpages to insert pdfs into the same document I get the following error: You have requested release '2020-10-01' of LaTex, but only release '2019-10-01' is available.  The PDF compiles, but the pages from the other pdf are blank.  The log shows the following:

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file S:/2020 Scallop RSA/Survey Estimates/2021/MA
B/MAB Individual Length Graphs.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.6>, bu
t at most version <1.5> allowed.  After some more digging I found that the log message should be fixed by specifying what PDF version to use by adding   `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5`.  This doesn't seem to help.  The PDF compiles, but there is a line at the top of the document: shipout/backgroundshipout/foreground and the pages in the compiled PDF are blank where the inserted pages should be - see image below example code.

Here is a small example with just the pdfpages package.  I did not include the actually document example because the code is long and the inserted pdf is 11 pgs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%preamble - set document settings

%package for loading images
\usepackage{graphicx}

%used to import multi page PDFs
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5

%start document

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove the pdfpages package - code below - the PDF compiles fine - see image below.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
    %preamble - set document settings
    
    %package for loading images
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    %used to import multi page PDFs
   %\usepackage{pdfpages}
    
    %\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5
    
    %start document
    
    \begin{document}
    
    Hello
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Prior to updating R and RStudio I did not have this issue.  I have tried removing and re-installing the pdfpackage in MikTex as well as removing and re-installing MikTex.  I also reverted back to an older version of R.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.  R version [32-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1

Comment: That's not the latest version of R. It's currently at [4.1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).

Comment: Yes I know - I had to use an older R version with an older MikTex version to get my PDF to compile.  Now I am having issues with using pdfpages.  When I used the updated R version I got a different error message and the PDF wouldn't compile.  To fix that issue I went back to older versions of both.